# What happens to objects instantiated inside static methods?

Tags: c#

I have a static object that looks somewhat like this:

```
public static class MyStaticObject
{    
   public static void SomeMethod()
   {
       MyObject TheObject = new MyObject();    

       //some long runnning tasks
   }
}
```

As you can see, when `SomeMethod()` runs, it creates a `MyObject`. What happens to this instantiated object after the method that created it returns? If `SomeMethod()` is called again while it's already executing in response to a previous method call, is there going to be a concurrency problem or does each method call instantiate its own `MyObject`?

Comment: You could try this out by adding 1 line of code to your program.

Comment: An object is reclaimed "at some point after" it is no longer strongly reachable. This may be after the long running task, depending on what is done (a variable that is not used after the long running task does *not* always ensure a strong reference in C#/.NET). The method being static has no effect, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TheObject` is just a local variable, and it behaves the same way regardless of the fact if the method is static or not.

So after the method returns, the object (if there are no more references to it) is ready for the garbage collector.

And in case of recursion, just another local variable will be created.

If you have `C/C++` background, the `TheObject` **is not** a `static` variable in `C/C++` terms.

Comment: So basically, if the method is called while it's running, the running tasks that execute on the second call will run with a new MyObject while the tasks running the initial call will have a reference to a different MyObject?

Comment: Yes. The behavior should be just the same as for a non-static member. But of course, if `TheObject` would be a `static` _field_ instead of a local variable, the story would be different.